# getting undefined from a function

Tags: javascript

Hello Write a function to convert a name into initials. This kata strictly takes two words with one space in between them. 
this is my code.

```
function abbrevName(name) {
    var first;
    var last;
    var new1 = name.split("")
    for (var i = 0; i < new1.length; i++) {
        if (new1[i] == new1.toUpperCase) {
            first = new1[i]
            if (new1[i] == new1.toUppercase && first == defined) {
                last = new1[i]
            }
            return first + "." + last;
        }


    }


    /enter code here
}
abbrevName("Faris Abutaya")
```

**i am getting undefined help me please**

Comment: `.toUpperCase` is a *function* and it has to be *called* in order to do anything useful in your code: `new1.toUpperCase()`. Also it has to be spelled consistently.

Comment: There are numerous errors here. To start to help you debug this yourself, first notice that your `return` statement is never executed (else you wouldn't get `undefined`) - what does that tell you? Then it's debugging 101: print stuff out to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting undefined from your function because you need to return something from it.

Try adding a `return` statement near the bottom and you'll get an output. What you actually *need* to return I'll leave up to you.

```
function abbrevName(name) {
  var first;
  var last;
  var new1 = name.split('');
  for (var i = 0; i < new1.length; i++) {
    if (new1[i] == new1.toUpperCase) {
      first = new1[i];
      if (new1[i] == new1.toUppercase && first == defined) {
        last = new1[i];
      }
      return first + '.' + last;
    }
  }

  return new1;
}

abbrevName('Faris Abutaya');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistake in the written code.

1. toUppercase is a function and it should be called as a method of the string. Therefore the code inside the first *if* statement would never run. For example:

```
    console.log( "h".toUppercase );
    //H
```

2. *new1* is an array of characters and you should call toUpperCase for each character not the whole array.

3.You should also check whether first is defined or not.

```
    function abbrevName(name) {
        var first;
        var last;
        var new1 = name.split("");
        for (var i = 0; i < new1.length; i++) {
            if (new1[i] === new1[i].toUpperCase() && new1[i] != " ") {
                if(first == undefined){
                    first = new1[i];
                }else if (new1[i] == new1[i].toUpperCase() && first != undefined){
                    last = new1[i];
                    return first + "." + last ;
                }
            }
        }
     }
     abbrevName("Faris Abutaya")
     //F.A
```

-It would be so much nicer to do it with RegEx. Because the code you wrote will just work in the times which user enters some names containing just 2 words and capitalizes first letters.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with your code are noted in comments here:

```
function abbrevName(name) {
    var first;
    var last;
    var new1 = name.split("")
    for (var i = 0; i < new1.length; i++) {
        if (new1[i] == new1.toUpperCase) {
            first = new1[i]
            // toUpperCase needs `()` to be called; new1 holds the array, not a letter; `== defined` is invalid
            if (new1[i] == new1.toUppercase && first == defined) {
                last = new1[i] // this statement will run as soon as first is found (so last = 'F')
            }
            return first + "." + last; // return happens as soon as first `if` condition is true
        }
    }
}
abbrevName("Faris Abutaya")
```

Here is revised code. Note that console.log statements help to debug because we can see  what each variable holds at various points in the script. (To see your browser console, use f12 or ctrl+shift+i)

```js
function abbrevName(name) {
  const letters = name.split(""); // Renamed new1 to letters
  let first ="", last = "";
  let firstFound = false, lastFound = false; // New variables
  console.log(letters);
  for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    console.log(letters[i]);
    if(letters[i] == letters[i].toUpperCase()){ //Compare letter to letter, not letter to array
      if(firstFound == false){
        firstFound = true; // Now we have a way to know last is coming
        first = letters[i];
        console.log("first: " + first);
      }
      else{ // firstFound is not false
        lastFound = true          
        last = letters[i];
        console.log("last: " + last);
      }    
    }
  }
  return first + "." + last; // return statement moved out of for loop
}
console.log(abbrevName("Faris Abutaya"));
```